# Java method not available in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using the ejml-library (written in Java) in a Kotlin project. I imported the library (everything seems to work fine) in IntelliJ. However, some methods which should be available (e.g. the inherited getDDRM() method of the class SimpleMatrix) are not recognized and I can't use them. Whats very weird is that the very same procedure used with Scala (also using IntelliJ) works. That is, in Scala I can access the method - with Kotlin I can't.

It would be great if someone could shed some light on this.

update:
the getDDRM() method is part of the abstract class "Class SimpleBase<T extends SimpleBase>" and has the following signature: "public DMatrixRMaj getDDRM()". In my code I call this method on an instance of class SimpleMatrix which is a concrete class inheriting the SimpleBaseClass –

I should also note that I rebuild it with gradle and the issue still persists.

IMPORTANT: I should add that I can access other methods defined in the very same class. For instance I can access the method getMatrix() which is just another method of the very same (abstract) class. In fact, IntelliJ's method completion shows me a whole list of methods - but the getDDRM() is missing. I really don't get the cause of this problem.

Update 2:

If it is of any help: When I do not use gradle but instead open a Kotlinproject in IntelliJ and add the libary jars manually then everything works fine. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you pls show the class and method?

Comment: the getDDRM() method is part of the abstract class

Comment: the getDDRM() method is part of the abstract class "Class SimpleBase<T extends SimpleBase<T>>" and has the following signature:    "public DMatrixRMaj getDDRM()". In my code i call this method on an instance of class SimpleMatrix which is a concrete class inheriting the SimpleBaseClass

Comment: @P.Jo don't put asked code in comments, edit your Question instead

Comment: Did you try to rebuild (`mvn clean compile` or `gradlew build`) project after importing `ejml-library` dependency ?

Comment: can you please check if you can directly use ".DDRM" on the SimpleMatrix object

Comment: this is not possible either

Comment: Kotlin interprets getter (and setter) methods as properties, so I'd look for a property called `ddrm` (or `DDRM`).

Comment: I did look this up. But here is the weird thing: IntelliJ (autocompletion) shows me something like matrix() as a property derived from the Java method getMatrix() but the same pattern strangely does not occur for getDDRM(), i.e. there is no property like dDRM or DDRM available.